# Statistical Significance on Marketing Experiment

Tags: experiment-design, marketing

Last week our marketing team did an experiment on discount voucher for a specific product.
Participants were randomly assigned to experimental group and control group.
There are 4 types of voucher amounts tested (5% discount, 10% discount, 15% discount, and 20% discount).
One group received one email for 3 days, the other group received one email for 5 days.
Each user can only use the voucher once.

This is the result of the experiment :

[image]

The problem is, I don't know much about statistics.
It seems that the 20% discount draws high attention. But how do I know if it's statistically significant?
And which voucher and email scheme that I should suggest to our marketing manager?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does the "3/5 days" signify? is the voucher only valid for 3 or 5 days? Or do the customers get multiple emails, with some customers getting one email every 3 days and others getting one every 5 days?

Comment: The voucher is valid for 7 days. One group of customers get one email each day for 3 days, and the other one get one email each day for 5 days.